# Mongoose Populate cant get this to work

Tags: mongoose

Very simple populate procedure im just missing something simple. I am at a loss. Using NodeJS, Mongoose for simple React thingy...

User Model

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
  },
  books: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Books"
    }
  ]
});

module.exports.User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Books Model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const BooksSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  },
  title: {
    type: String
  },
  author: {
    type: String
  },
  description: {
    type: String
  }
});

module.exports.Books = mongoose.model("Books", BooksSchema);
```

Function call

```
router.get("/test", (req, res) => {
  User.find()
    .populate("books")
    .exec()
    .then(user => {
      res.json(user);
    });
});
```

This is an abbreviated concept compared to what I am actuall doing. I thought I understood but apparently not.

Currently, I have one user (A) that has two books. I believe I should get the email, password, id, and an array of book ids when I run this route in Postman...or so I think. Please let me know what I am doing wrong or give me a simple explanation...Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

You should just export the schemas:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model("Book", BookSchema); // Notice here "Book"
```

Then when you do your find make sure you use the exact name of the schema:

```
router.get("/test", (req, res) => {
  User.find()
    .populate("books")
    .exec()
    .then(user => {
      res.json(user);
    });
});
```

I created your models/schemas and tested it. Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Doesnt work for me. Granted the schema for user has validation, that works flawlessly outside this populate fiasco. I believe the ".populate('Book')" should actually be ".populate('books')" as that is the field I am trying to populate. Ive tried it every way I can think of.

Comment: You probably did since I did test what I wrote above locally and it did work.

Comment: In your case is `books` correct I had my schema with slightly different names

Comment: Thanks. I had to use an actionCreator instead. I will go back and use populate eventually...

Answer (score 0):

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
  },
  books: [
    {
      type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],//you have to make this array of ids 
      ref: "Books"
    }
  ]
});

module.exports.User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Books Model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const BooksSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  },
  title: {
    type: String
  },
  author: {
    type: String
  },
  description: {
    type: String
  }
});

module.exports.Books = mongoose.model("Books", BooksSchema);

Function call

router.get("/test", (req, res) => {
  User.find()
    .populate({path:"books",model:"Books"})
    .exec()
    .then(user => {
      res.json(user);
    });
});
```